# Image isn't correctly rendered

Tags: support, documentation, markdown, documentation-editor

I just tried editing a remark in docs. I added a picture. The preview looked fine. When I saved SO is some how parsing the text wrong (I guess that assumes it saved exactly what I entered and is only parsing it).

In any case the docs page is now broken. Two remarks got merged and the whole remarks section is now not editable at all as in something about the broken parsing has made the page not function correctly

Or maybe I was just banned from editing. I have no idea. All I know I can't edit my edit to try to adjust it so it doesn't break the page.

[The page is here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/2288/console#t=201612090359118217767) and if you scroll down to the "Safari" section you'll see the image tag is not showing the image and that section has been wrongly merged with the Opera section.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to have been caused by additional text following the line which had the image link reference. I've made [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/114866?filter-tags=javascript) that fixes this by adding a new line directly after the image link.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. That still doesn't actually fix the bugs though. #1 being the preview worked and #2 being I couldn't fix it myself because it wouldn't let me edit